# Sorting data in MySQL and then transferring highest values to other table

Tags: mysql

I have a table `packs` with four columns INT `ID` (Primary Key), Char `Code`, DATETIME `Approved`, and INT `Score`. For each unique code, I want to sort the entries associated with it by score and then transfer the `ID` with the highest score with a **non-NULL** DATETIME to a second table `airports`. The airports table is already built with Char `Code` as a the primary key, with a currently NULL INT column `RecommendedPack`. The ID associated with the highest score for that code (if applicable) should fill that column. I've only done pretty basic SQL before, so I'm not really sure how to begin with this problem. I am using MySQL 5.7 for reference.

Sample Data:

```
ID   Code   Approved  Score
---------------------------
1    KLAX   Valid DT  1
2    KBOS   Valid DT  0
3    KLAX   Valid DT  -1
4    KSFO   Valid DT  0
5    KSFO   NULL      5
6    KSMO   Valid DT  1
```

Expected result:

```
    Code   ...  RecommendedPack
    ---------------------------
    KBOS        2
    KLAX        1
    KSFO        4
    KSMO        6
```

The suggested duplicate does not solve my problem because I need to find that max without specifying a threshold.

Comment: add  a 'proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: @scaisEdge Done

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)